# How to deal with product images in django oscar API?

Tags: django-oscar

I found only one way to upload images, here is a JSON request:
(http://djoscar.na4u.ru/api/admin/products/my_id):

Content-Type application/json

```
{
    "images": [ {
        "original":  "https://habrastorage.org/r/w60/webt/60/4c/bb/604cbb3558921501706659.jpeg",
        "caption":  "2",
        "display_order": 2
    }],
    "uid": "09d89514-81c7-11ed-975d-52540001e6af",
}
```

This is not very convenient, I would like to just transfer the file, how and in what format can I do this? Just wondering how do I delete/replace images?